# Geometric fundamental group and algebraically closed residue field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory, fundamental-group

my questions relates to the following talk of Tsuji:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2brDj26phP0

At around 10:30 of the video, Tsuji is interrupted by a man stating that his construction does not work if $k$ is not algebraically closed. I do not understand this remark at all.

For those of you that do not want to have a look at the video here is a quick summary of the part in question:

The assumptions are as follows: $K$ a complete valuation field of mixed characteristic (0,p) with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ uniformizer $\pi$ and residue field $k$ (*algebraically closed*). $A$ an semistable algebra i.e. $$ A \underset{étale}{\leftarrow} \mathcal{O}_K[T_1,\cdots, T_c, \cdots, T_d]/(T_1 T_2 \cdots T_c-\pi)$$ let $\mathcal{K}=Frac(A)$ and $\overline{\mathcal{K}}$ an algebraical closure with $\overline{K} \subset \overline{\mathcal{K}}$. For every finite extension $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{L} \subset \overline{\mathcal{K}}$ denote by $A_{\mathcal{L}}$ the integral closure of $A$ in $\mathcal{L}$. Define the set $$ S:=\big\{\mathcal{L} \, \vert \, A_{\mathcal{L}}[\frac{1}{T_1\cdots T_d}] /A[\frac{1}{T_1\cdots T_d}] \, \text{étale}\big\}$$ such that $Spec(A)$ is connected and $Spec(A/\pi A)\neq 0$ and $Spec(A/\sum_{i \in I} T_iA)$ is irreducible or empty for all $I \subset\{1,\cdots,d\}$. Set $\mathcal{K}^{ur}=\cup_{\mathcal{L}\in S} \mathcal{L}$. 
He then states that $$ Gal(\mathcal{K}^{ur}/\mathcal{K}\overline{K})= \pi_1(A[1/T_1\cdots T_d] \otimes _{\mathcal{O}_K} \overline{K},Spec(\overline{K})).$$ Why is this not true if $k$ is not algebraically closed? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: (That man was Ofer Gabber.)

Comment: Speaking as somebody who has been interrupted by Gabber: Gabber is always correct.

Comment: For the $\pi_1$ to make sense, the scalar extension to $\overline{K}$ (inside the $\pi_1$) must have connected spectrum. But if $A[1/\pi]$ contains a non-trivial finite (separable) extension $K'/K$ then this fails because scalar extension will contain $K'\otimes_K\overline{K}$ which has disconnected spectrum. If $k$ is not algebraically closed then (assuming Tsuji only considers $k$ that is at least perfect) one can easily make such $A$ by replacing $O_K$ with $O_{K'}$ for non-trivial unramified $K'/K$. So algebraic closedness of $k$ is necessary. Sufficiency is the real content, of course.

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't doubting he was right, just didnt understanding why he was. Thank you for that @nfdc23. If you want to make it an answer i will accept it.

Comment: P.S. If you could Point me to a good resource for such things. I would be very happy.

Comment: Nevermind the reference. Serre's local fields covers this. Thanks again, and sorry for the rather stupid question.